# Toggle text when click on another button of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of box with text/images and a button for displaying more/less text. When I click to another button of item, The box text where I was it closed, but the text didn't change too to "More details" again.

You can check it in https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/

A screenshot with the problem: I clicked first in the second item's button, next I clicked in the first item's button. The box text closed, but the button's text didn't change to "more details" (más detalles) again.

[image]

```js
   

 $("document").ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Más detalles') {
          $(this).text('Menos detalles');
        } else {
          $(this).text('Más detalles');
        }
        
        var $p1 = $(this).next(".p1");
        var $p1img = $(this).parents().eq(4).find(".p1-img");
      
        $p1.toggle();
        $p1img.toggle();
      
        $(".p1").not($p1).hide();
        $(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();
        
      });
});
```

```css
.p1, .p1-img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="event-56092" class="ect-list-post ect-featured-event  data-parent-post " id=" 56053">
        <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
            <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/50008823_1936412149789348_6701274349090897920_n-1024x715.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
                <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
                    <div class="ect-list-date">
                        <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule">
                            <span class="ev-day">25</span>
                            <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span>
                            <span class="ev-yr">2019</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ect-list-post-right">
            <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
                <div class="ect-list-description">
                    <h2 class="ect-list-title">
                        <a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores" rel="bookmark">VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores</a>
                    </h2>
                    <button class="btn1 button-more svg" >Más detalles</button>
                    <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="ect-event-content">
                            <p>Desde el lunes 21 de enero y hasta el martes 18 de junio, todos los socios de los Centros Municipales de Mayores que participan en la XXIII Campaña de Atención al Mayor, podrán inscribirse en las diferentes actividades de la VI Escuelas Deportivas para mayores. Se impartirán clases de pádel, tenis de mesa, petanca, rutas...</p>
                            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p1-venue">
                    <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue">
                        <span class="ect-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address">
                            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/lugar/area-de-atencion-al-mayor-ayuntamiento-de-badajoz/" title="Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz">Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz</a>,
                            <span class="tribe-address">
                                <span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span>
                                <span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span>
                                <abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr" title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr>
                                <span class="tribe-country-name">España</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ect-google">
                            <a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Badajoz+Badajoz+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="ect-rate-area">
                            <span class="ect-rate-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ect-rate">Gratuito</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: If I open an item with the button and click on another button's item, the text don't toggle, only the text box. I will upload a photo.

Comment: when text is closed(trimed) button says Más detalles meaning More details & when text is open button says Menos detalles meaning Less details. What is your requirement in the above question?

Comment: When you have a text box open with the button's text on "Less details"  and u click on another button in the item list, the box text closes but the button's text (Less details), didn't change automatically to "More details".

Comment: use `$(".btn1").not(this).text('Más detalles');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem if you change the text of other `.btn1` just like you are hiding other `.p1-img` and `.p1-img`. This can be done easily by using

`$(".btn1").not(this).text('Más detalles');`

just after

`$(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();`

as follows;

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Más detalles') {
          $(this).text('Menos detalles');
        } else {
          $(this).text('Más detalles');
        }
        
        var $p1 = $(this).next(".p1");
        var $p1img = $(this).parents().eq(4).find(".p1-img");
      
        $p1.toggle();
        $p1img.toggle();
      
        $(".p1").not($p1).hide();
        $(".p1-img").not($p1img).hide();
        $(".btn1").not(this).text('Más detalles');
        
      });
});
```

```css
.p1, .p1-img {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="details.css">
    <script src="details.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="event-56092" class="ect-list-post ect-featured-event  data-parent-post " id=" 56053">
        <div class="ect-list-post-left ">
            <div class="ect-list-img" style="background-image:url('https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/50008823_1936412149789348_6701274349090897920_n-1024x715.jpg');background-size:cover;background-position:center center;">
                <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="Imagen del evento" alt="Magazine 1" rel="bookmark">
                    <div class="ect-list-date">
                        <div class="ect-date-area default-schedule">
                            <span class="ev-day">25</span>
                            <span class="ev-mo">febrero</span>
                            <span class="ev-yr">2019</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ect-list-post-right">
            <div class="ect-list-post-right-table">
                <div class="ect-list-description">
                    <h2 class="ect-list-title">
                        <a class="ect-event-url" href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" title="VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores" rel="bookmark">VI Escuelas Deportivas para Mayores</a>
                    </h2>
                    <button class="btn1 button-more svg" >Más detalles</button>
                    <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="ect-event-content">
                            <p>Desde el lunes 21 de enero y hasta el martes 18 de junio, todos los socios de los Centros Municipales de Mayores que participan en la XXIII Campaña de Atención al Mayor, podrán inscribirse en las diferentes actividades de la VI Escuelas Deportivas para mayores. Se impartirán clases de pádel, tenis de mesa, petanca, rutas...</p>
                            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <button class="btn1 button-more svg" >Más detalles</button>
                    <div class="p1" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="ect-event-content">
                            <p>Desde el lunes 21 de enero y hasta el martes 18 de junio, todos los socios de los Centros Municipales de Mayores que participan en la XXIII Campaña de Atención al Mayor, podrán inscribirse en las diferentes actividades de la VI Escuelas Deportivas para mayores. Se impartirán clases de pádel, tenis de mesa, petanca, rutas...</p>
                            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/agenda/vi-escuelas-deportivas-para-mayores/2019-02-25/" class="ect-events-read-more" rel="bookmark">Ir al evento »</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="p1-venue">
                    <div class="ect-list-venue  default-venue">
                        <span class="ect-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ect-venue-details ect-address">
                            <a href="https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/lugar/area-de-atencion-al-mayor-ayuntamiento-de-badajoz/" title="Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz">Area de atención al Mayor , Ayuntamiento de Badajoz</a>,
                            <span class="tribe-address">
                                <span class="tribe-locality">Badajoz</span>
                                <span class="tribe-delimiter">,</span>
                                <abbr class="tribe-region tribe-events-abbr" title="Badajoz">Badajoz</abbr>
                                <span class="tribe-country-name">España</span>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ect-google">
                            <a class="tribe-events-gmap" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Badajoz+Badajoz+Espa%C3%B1a" title="Click para ver mapa de Google" target="_blank">+ Google Map</a>
                        </span>
                        <div class="ect-rate-area">
                            <span class="ect-rate-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-money" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </span>
                            <span class="ect-rate">Gratuito</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Caution:** All buttons you using to toggle on [page](https://www.lagaleramagazine.es/) must belong to `.btn1` .